# How to narrow the size of webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-chrome-extension

In my app we are reviewing the webpages. There is a button which loads the webpage for ex-: As shown in [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cd4Ww.jpg) after clicking button it opened apple.com Now I want to show the webpage in every device width but while doing it the webpage loses its responsiveness. Select Resolution(marked with red ink) is chrome extension which is meant to change the width of any webpage and the url of webpage should not be changed(can't use frames).[image after changing width](https://i.stack.imgur.com/okMR1.png)
[Result should be like this but without the use of iframe/frames](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0eVCV.png)

```
var html = '<div class="captureMainWrap" style="position:absolute; top:100px; right: 10px;"><div class="captureCollapse" style="cursor: pointer;"><i class="captureAccordian fa fa-caret-right" style="color:#fff; margin: 11px 5px 0 5px; font-size:25px;"></i></div><div class="capture"><div id="screenEmulator" style="margin-top:6px;"><select class="selDevice" id="selectDevice"><option disabled selected hidden>Select Resolution</option><option data-height="100%" data-width="100%">My Screen</option><option data-height="568px" data-width="320px">iphone 5s (320 X 568)</option><option data-height="627px" data-width="375px">iphone 6s (375 X 627)</option><option data-height="1024px" data-width="768px">ipad portrait (768 X 1024)</option><option data-height="768px" data-width="1024px">ipad landscape (1024 X 768)</option><option data-height="567px" data-width="360px">Nexus 5 (360 X 567)</option><option data-height="659px" data-width="412px">Nexus 6 (412 X 659)</option></select></div><div class="append"></div><div class="onCamera"><i class="fa fa-camera" id="onCameraClick" style="font-size:25px text-shadow: 0px 0px 3px #00fa91;"></i><div></div></div> </div></div>';
$('body').append(html);
var div ='<div id="maindiv"></div>';
var body = $('body');
var head = $('head');
$('html').append(div);
$('#maindiv').append(body);
$('#maindiv').append(head);

$('#selectDevice').change(function(){
var selectHeight=$("#selectDevice").find('option:selected').attr('data-height');
var selectWidth=$("#selectDevice").find('option:selected').attr('data-width');
if(($("#selectDevice").val()=="My Screen")){
   $('#maindiv').css('width','100px');
}
else{
   $('#maindiv').css('width','100px');        
}
```

});

Comment: You are changing width of some div, not width of viewport.

Comment: Also, unrelated to your problem: Chrome (edit: and other browsers) has built-in mobile debugging (F12, then Ctrl+Shift+M)

Comment: @ChrisG Same with Firefox

Comment: You can put the web pages in an iframe, and change the iframe width when you select different devices will.

Comment: @MudOnTire Cant use iframe the url will get changed.

Comment: @ChrisG 

I know about google developers tool but i need to add that in my extension

Comment: @Justinas result should be like as shown in link. I tried viewport but didn't effected like this.  https://i.stack.imgur.com/0eVCV.png